# Master-Slave semi circle replication not working in MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, master-slave

I didn't know how to describe it so I am calling it semi circle. Here's what I am doing.

Server A
Server B = This is slave of Server A
Server C = This is slave of Server B

When I update something on Server A then it is reflected on Server B. But the same change is not reflected on Server C.

Only when I update something on Server B then change is reflected on Server C.

How do I make it so any changes done on Server A will come to Server B (which is already working) and then it goes to Server C?

**EDIT**
Upon investigation I found out that when I make some change on Server A then its log file position changes. But when those changes are reflected on Server B then Server B log file position doesn't change. It is because of this reason Server C doesn't know if there has been any change on Server B unless I explicitly change something (insert,update,delete) on Server B.

So is there a way to tell MySQL to increment log file position when Slave is receiving updates from Master?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI—this is typically called a replication relay chain.  In order to turn this on, you will have to make sure the following settings are set on server B:

```
log_bin
log_slave_updates
```

This will tell server B to update its log position when updates from A are received.  The documentation for this can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-options-slave.html#option_mysqld_log-slave-updates) (emphasis added):

> Normally, a slave does not write any updates that are received from a 
>   master server to its own binary log. This option causes the slave to 
>   write the updates performed by its SQL thread to its own binary log. 
>   For this option to have any effect, the slave must also be started with 
>   the **--log-bin** option to enable binary logging. **--log-slave-updates is 
>   used when you want to chain replication servers.** For example, you might 
>   want to set up replication servers using this arrangement
>
> `A -> B -> C`
>
> Here, A serves as the master for the slave B, and B serves as the master 
>   for the slave C. For this to work, B must be both a master and a slave. 
>   You must start both A and B with **--log-bin** to enable binary logging, and 
>   B with the **--log-slave-updates** option so that updates received from A 
>   are logged by B to its binary log.

Comment: Near the top, you have `log_server_updates`... isn't that `log_slave_updates`?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot:  right you are.  Will fix.